# MVC view/form not posting back to itself

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

**I have updated the question with more information.**

I have a view like this (simplified version):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

            <fieldset>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RememberMe)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.RememberMe)
                </div>

                <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/login_button.png")" alt="Login" />

            </fieldset>
        }
```

Suddenly, while integrating lots of other code for the last 3 hours, I noticed just now that my view has stopped causing a post/back. It's a simple login form.

I see that there's no submit type in here. But I wonder how it was posting back to itself earlier.
What should i change?

**UPDATE**

I just realized it's not posting back to the Index (httpPost) because I have a CheckUserName remote validation in the same controller. When I remove the remote validation, it works. If I introduce it back, it doesn't. Here's my remote validation.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult CheckUserName(string userName)
{
    using (var context = new Presentation.Models.PMSEntities())
    {
        context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        Func<User, bool> predicate = u => u.UserName.SameAs(userName) && u.Status.SameAs("Active");

        return Json(context.Users.Any(predicate), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

And I have the `RemoteAttribute` set on the appropriate field.

Comment: You have source control right? Do a history compare and see what changed.

Comment: Yes what subsequesnt code changes have you made since it was working.

Comment: Are you sure you still have a POST method in the controller?

Comment: does it show any validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

you can just use [HttpPost] on Action method for simple forms

or

you can try this when uploading files or working on complex forms

@Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { SearchModel = Model }, FormMethod.Post)

Answer (score 0):

`input` with `type="image"` acts as a submit button. You are missing quotes for the src attribute - `@Url.Content` returns the url without quotes, so try adding them.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Html.BeginForm()` creates a `<form>` that POSTs to the current action .
You need to pass the action name to `BeginForm`.

Ex:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    }
```

Comment: You can check the requests made using `Fiddler` or `Firebug in firefox`